# continuously loop through values in an array using Baconjs

Tags: javascript, frp, bacon.js

I have an array of strings `var strs = ['a','b','c']` and I want to use a `Bacon.interval(2000)` to return the values continuously to `onValue`

The closest thing I can think of to create this is

```
var stream = Bacon.interval(2000);
var i = 0;
stream.onValue(function (v) {
    if (i >= strs.length) i=0;
    else i ++;
    strs[i];
})
```

not a very reactive solution, I am aware

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Bacon.repeatedly(2000, ['a', 'b', 'c'])
  .onValue(function(v) {
    console.log(v);
  });
```

Comment: OP probably wants [`Bacon.repeatedly`](https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js/#bacon-repeatedly) rather than sequentially

Comment: thanks! quick follow up, is there also a subscriber for it to immediately output the first item instead of after the first 2 seconds?

Comment: You could use `Bacon.repeatedly(2000, ['b', 'c']).toProperty('a')` which should give that behavior.